# Regular Expressions for JavaScript not normal emails

Tags: javascript, regex

I have RE like this:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi
```

to find emails, now I need regular expression to also find emails like this:

```
a.p.agarwaal AT gmail DOT com
a.p.agarwaal (at) gmail.com
a.p.agarwaal_AT_gmail_DOT_com
```

Comment: don't people use formats like that because they _don't_ want their address parsed?

Comment: "Can u help me please." that was not KINDLY ?

Comment: -1 If you were able to write the first regular expression, what problem do you have to write an extension that covers `@|\(at\)|_AT_)`?

Comment: BTW, your original regular expression has some issue. It will accept even if there is a . (dot) end of of email..

Comment: @masum7: dot in the end is a valid character actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(?:@| AT | \(AT\) |_AT_)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)
```

Comment: How do you feel after helping spammers? :-D

Comment: Man u DONT know me !!! I am not spammer !!! I just need to finish school project !

Comment: Thank You very much it works !!!! And I am not a spammer !!!! Just student !!!

Comment: he didn't say you were a spammer, the problem is that spammers could come across this answer. now that you have a solution, please close the question if you have any good sense.

Comment: so I have my answer it works i am very happy feel free to remove this topic from Internet if this will help u

Comment: Anyone knowing a bit of regular expressions could code that. And remember that even [virus or illegal-activity related questions are allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187593)

Comment: Security by obscurity is no security at all, @zerkms. Not all of the spammers these days are know-nothing script kiddies.

Comment: On the other hand, crowd-sourcing your homework isn't particularly ethical either, @user2982527.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: "Security by obscurity is no security at all" --- so if you see a theft at your neighbor's door you will kindly tell them what stone they keep emergency key under instead of calling police? Just following your idea that helping doing bad is good.

Comment: @zerkms - Histrionics doesn't take the place of sound reasoning. If you equate a regular expression directly with theft, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way: http://jsfiddle.net/29h4dL9h/

```
    var email0 = "a.p.agarwaal@gmail.com"
    var email1 = "a.p.agarwaal (at) gmail.com"
    var email2 = "a.p.agarwaal_AT_gmail.com"
    var email3 = "a.p.agarwaal AT gmail DOT com"

    alert(validateEmail(email0))
    alert(validateEmail(email1))
    alert(validateEmail(email2))
    alert(validateEmail(email3))

    function validateEmail(email) 
    { 
        var exp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+(\@|\s\(at\)\s|\sAT\s|\_AT\_)(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+(\.|\sDOT\s))+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/ig;
        return exp.test(email);
    }
```